# unable to login in xubuntu 13.10

Tags: xubuntu

I have install xubuntu 13.10 and i installed cinnamon 2.I loged out to test the new cinnamon instalation choosing the session i noticed that there is a session named "cairo" (cairo dock is installed too)and i tryied to login to see what it is but what i got was a black screen.the system is setup to autologing without asking a pass, so every time i reboot the system boots automaticaly to cairo session , which was the last session i tried to boot, and i allways get a black screen.Is there any way to change that????

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, you could log-in into a tty by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F6 and uninstall cairo-dock like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove cairo-dock
```

Then reboot, or reload lightdm (sudo service lightdm restart) and it should log to the default Desktop Environment, since the cairo session won't be installed.

When you finish, if you want to recover cairo-dock, just reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

Comment: just tried with no luck i got the same black screen.

Comment: is there any way to change the "autologin" to ask for password????

Comment: Finally i found the answer, loged-in to tty by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F6,
then typed " sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf " and this is what i got: 

[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=username <--- change to false
autologin-user-timeout=0 <--- change to 30
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
greeter-session=pantheon-greeter
user-session=pantheon

I saved it and reboot it and that was all
sorry but i don't know how to write on code